# Image with dynamic url won't link anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Absolute newb to coding so my apologies if my question is phrased poorly! I'm trying to get an image that has a dynamic url to send users to another url when it's clicked on. The image has a dynamic url so that I can remotely update the gif if needed without caching issues. My problem is that I can't seem to get the image to link to anywhere when it's clicked on. I've tried putting it in a div container and using the usual  tags but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get the image to link the person to a new url location when they click on it?

Here's the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd;
var myImage = new Image(400, 190);
myImage.src = 'https://www.conatycatering.com/image/uploads/signatures/topsignature' + today + ".gif";
document.body.appendChild(myImage);

$("a#url").attr("href", url)
});
</script>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: You're using `url` in your `href` attribute but `url` isn't defined anywhere so the link won't go anywhere. Define `url` (`var url = 'http://somelink.com'`) before you set the `href` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have previously tried doing that but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to go anywhere if I put in it. Where in the code should it go? Currently I've tried it here:
 `var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd;'
var url = 'http://www.somelink.com';
var myImage = new Image(400, 190);
myImage.src = 'https://www.conatycatering.com/image/uploads/signatures/topsignature' + today + ".gif' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one part you were missing is declaring the `url`. Once you've done that however, you want the image to be inside the anchor, not the general body.

So you don't want to use `document.body.appendChild` which just adds the image to the HTML body, you instead want the image inside the anchor, which you can see working below, by setting the `html()` of the anchor.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd;
  var myImage = new Image(400, 190);
  myImage.src = 'https://www.conatycatering.com/image/uploads/signatures/topsignature' + today + ".gif";
  
  var url = 'http://example.com' // REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR URL
  $("a#url").attr("href", url)
  $('a#url').html(myImage)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="url"></a>
```

I've removed a lot of extra stuff and used a placeholder image for brevity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help! As I said I'm a complete newb to coding so I'm a bit confused of how to add your fix into my code with the dynamic url aspect needed in mine etc. I tried with a html previewer and can't seem to add your fix correctly.  Is there any chance you could use the full code I posted and include your fix in it? Thank you again!

Comment: I've updated the code to use your code, since you asked nicely. Just be aware that StackOverflow is for general help, not many people will just do the code for you (I'm nice) because the idea is to learn from help and advice. You don't learn as much if people just write the code for you.

Comment: Ah thank you! I understand and I really appreciate it as I'll certainly be using it to better understand why it works and what I was doing incorrectly. Cheers! :)